# Python: Write text into database and read it

Tags: python, database, text, kivy

I am trying to make an app, where you can write your goals and then in another screen would be your data shown. in goals screen you input personal goals which are assigned into your behavior model. I think that there could be more mistakes because i am beginner. I dont know what i have to do. When i write sth into text input, it give me an error. please can anyone help me?

in main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')
from database import DataBase
from helpers import screen_helper

class MyGoalsScreen (Screen):
    model = ObjectProperty(None)
    ciel1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    created = ObjectProperty(None)
    current = ""

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        ciel1, created = DataBase.get_user(self.current)
        self.ciel1.text = "ciel 1 je: " + ciel1
        self.model.text = "model je " + self.current
        self.created.text = "Created On: " + created

class GoalsScreen(Screen):
    model = ObjectProperty (None)
    ciel1= ObjectProperty(None)

    def submit(self):
        if self.ids.model.text != "":
            DataBase.add_user(self.model.text, self.ciel1.text)
        else:
            pass

class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "500"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"

        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen

MainApp().run()
```

in helpers.py

```
<MyGoalsScreen>:
    name: "mygoals"  
    ciel1: ciel1
    model: model
    created: created
            
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: ciel1
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.9}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "goal 1 is: "
            
        Label:
            id: model
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.7}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "I am model "   
    
        Label:
            id: created
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.5}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "Created: "

<GoalsScreen>:
    name: "goals"
    model: model
    ciel1: ciel1
    
   
    MDList:
        OneLineIconListItem:
            text: "Define your goals to improve yourself"
        MDLabel:                 
            size_hint: .9,None
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0.96,0.79,0.09, 1
            text: "which model of behavior you are"
                
        MDTextFieldRect:
            id: model
            multiline: True
            size_hint: 0.9,None
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
        
        MDLabel: 
            size_hint: None, None
            text: "question for goal 1?"
                
        MDTextFieldRect:
            id: ciel1
            multiline: True
            size_hint: 0.9,None
            hint_text: "My goal 1"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}

    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon: "play-circle-outline"
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {"center_x" :0.5, "center_y":0.08}
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        on_release: root.submit()
```

in database.py

```
import datetime


class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.users = None
        self.file = None
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        self.file = open(self.filename, "r")
        self.users = {}

        for line in self.file:
            model, ciel1, created = line.strip().split(";")
            self.users[model] = (ciel1, created)

        self.file.close()

    def get_user(self, model):
        if model in self.users:
            return self.users[model]
        else:
            return -1

    def add_user(self, model, ciel1):
        if model.strip() not in self.users:
            self.users[model.strip()] = (ciel1.strip(), DataBase.get_date())
            self.save()
            return 1
        else:
            print("ciele su zadane")
            return -1

    def save(self):
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            for user in self.users:
                f.write(user + ";" + self.users[user][0] + ";" + self.users[user][1] + ";" + self.users[user][2] + "\n")

    @staticmethod
    def get_date():
        return str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(" ")[0]
```

and error

```
File "C:/Users/Stanko/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 369, in submit
     DataBase.add_user(self.model.text, self.ciel1.text)
 TypeError: add_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ciel1'
```

Comment: If you really want to save to a database look at sqlite3. Perfect for this application

Comment: The `add_user()` method of your `Database` class is an instance method, but you are using it as a static method (class method). I suspect that somewhere in your code you should do something like `db = Database('mydb.db')`. Then everywhere that you use `Database.`, you should use `db.` instead.